# char(string) to integer

Tags: c++

I was wondering  how to compare one array into two arrays but with some rules:
In my code I need to type 8 digits to make the cycle - OK, I did it. Now I need to compare the `array = m[3]` to two different arrays:

first array must be with `(if m[i]%2==0) ...`

second array must be with `(if m[i]%2!=0) ...`

So if I type from keyboard those three rows in my Main array `(m[3])`:

```
12345678
12345689
12344331
```

After typing them, I need to set the in those two different arrays and here I think I need to make the `char(string)` to `integer` to make the check with `%`, or to somehow do the check only on the last digit (it will work the same way).
So here goes the next step after typing the 3 rows:

```
arrA=12345678
arrB=12345689 12344331


#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>
#include <string>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <stdlib.h>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int i,n;
    char m[3];
    for(i=1; i<=3; i++)
    {
        cout<<i<<". Fak nomer: "<<endl;
        do
        {
            cin>>m[i];
            gets(m);
        }
        while (strlen(m)!=7);
        cout<<"As integer: "<<atoi(m);
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't fully understand what the goal is, but the for-loop in your code must definitely be corrected to `for (i = 0 ; i < 3 ; ++i)`, otherwise it will run beyond the end of the array.

Comment: when i have 12345678 and 12345679 typed i need to show them in two different arrays for countable and uncountable

Comment: Please improve your expression.I just cann't understand.

Comment: ok as i said in above comment - I have array in type char[3] so when i have the result from keyboard i need to check that number to be countable and uncountable and show the second result in another two arrays based on countable numbers and uncountable number (but in my case i have digits and not number) i need to make it a number first or somehow another way .. that is why i'm posting here

Comment: `atoi` is definitely you you turn a string into an integer...what problem are you having?

Comment: the problem is that on digits 12345678 - integer is shown as 2345678

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I understand, you are trying to read three positive integers into an array called `m`, but you want to ensure the following:

- all three number have eight digits
- the first number (`m[0]`) is even
- the second number (`m[1]`) is odd

It would be a lot easier if `m` can be an array of integers, then a conversion from a string to an int is not required. To read the three integers from the console, use this:

```
// m is now an array of integers
int m[3];
// loops from m[0] to m[2]
for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
{
    cout<<i<<": "<<endl;
    do
    {
        cin>>m[i];
    }
    while (!(m[i] >= 1e7 && m[i] < 1e8));
    // m[i] must be greater than or equal to 10000000 and less than 100000000
    //  before continuing
}
```

By making `m` an array of integers, checking for even or odd becomes easier:

```
if (m[0] % 2 == 0)
    cout << "m[0] is even" << endl;
if (m[1] % 2 != 0)
    cout << "m[1] is odd" << endl;
```

Comment: ok the is working now fine (i didnt know that function "1e7"... ) But when i press enter to the last one number here is some kind of error:
"Run Time Check Failure #2 - Stack around the variable 'm' was corrupted"

Comment: In your original code, you used `for(i=1; i<=3; i++)`. Make sure you change it to `for(i=0; i<3; i++)`. Remember that arrays start at index 0.

Comment: first time it was something like warning in the end, now it is error with the same type .. run time check ... bla bla

Comment: lol wait here it goes ... on must be i<3 not i<=3 as u said .. i didnt see it . Thanks a lot !!!

Answer (score 0):

not sure if i understand your problem, but why not just change

```
char* m[3];
```

to

```
int m[3];
```

you'd probably want to redo the loop

```
int m[3];    
for(i=0; i<3; i++)
{
    cout<<i+1<<". Fak nomer: "<<endl;

    cin>>m[i]; 

    while (m[i] < 1000000 || m[i] >9999999)
    {
        cout<<"number is less/more than 7 digits. Try again:"<<endl;
        cin>>m[i];
    }

    cout<<"As integer: "<< m[i];
}
```

Comment: it should work because we have changed the m[i] to an integer.

Answer (score 0):

It is difficult to understand exactly what you're trying to achieve.

If I understand it correctly, you're trying to get 3 7-character input strings (of integers) from the user, and then check each integer of the first string in turn against the same position character in the other 2 strings?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    std::string m[3];
    for(int i = 0; i < 3; ++i)
    {
        std::cout << i + 1 << ". Fak nomer: "<< std::endl;
        do
        {
            std::cin >> m[i];
        }
        while (m[i].size() != 7);
    }

    // we have enforced each string to be 7 characters long, check each character in turn
    for(int i = 0; i < 7; ++i)
    {
        // get the i'th character of each string, and subtract the ascii '0' character to convert to an integer
        int a1 = m[0][i] - '0';
        int a2 = m[1][i] - '0';
        int a3 = m[2][i] - '0';

        std::cout << "checking " << a1 << " against " << a2 << " and " << a3 << std::endl;

        if (a1 % a2 == 0)
            std::cout << a1 << " % " << a2 << " == 0" << std::endl;

        if (a1 % a3 != 0)
            std::cout << a1 << " % " << a3 << " != 0" << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```